# SpotFire 7 Add (OData) connection to standard data connections from plugin

Tags: spotfire, data-connections

We are developing a SpotFire 7 plugin.
The functionality is adding a Wizard on top of creating a standard data source.

We want to supply a dropdownlist to select a filter parameter for our source. The resulting mashup will be saved as library item and be accessible from the WebPlayer.

For this reason i will have to create a data source with the fixed value parameter filled.

How can i access the datasources and add a new one to it from the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It is the reference to the Tibco's documentation. Did you read it ?

http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Tutorials/HowToCreateSimpleDataSource.aspx